# Check if data.frame column, of type list, is NULL

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

How do I check which rows of  my column "Subdocuments" are NULL, and then return the rows are not NULL The column "Subdocuments" is of type "list".

The following lines of code i tried, but the doesn't work, something similar should be the solution.

```
  newdata<- data[!is.null(data$Subdocuments),]
  newdata<- data[!is.null(unlist(data$Subdocuments)),]
  newdata<- data[!is.na(data$Subdocuments),]
  newdata<- data[!is.na(unlist(data$Subdocuments)),]
```

Here is the data.

```
 data <- structure(list(ID = c("1", "2", "3"), Country = c("Netherlands", 
        "Germany", "Belgium"), Subdocuments = list(structure(list(Value = c("5", 
        "5", "1", "3", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "5", "3", "2", "4", "5", 
        "5", "2"), Label = c("Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5", 
        "Test6", "Test7", "Test8", "Test9", "Test10", "Test11", "Test12", 
        "Test13", "Test14", "Test15", "Test16"), Year = c(2001, 2002, 
        2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 
        2014, 2015, 2016)), .Names = c("Value", "Label", "Year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
        16L)), structure(list(Value = c("5", "4", "3", "2", "2", "2", 
        "1", "1", "5", "4", "4", "4", "5", "1", "1", "3"), Label = c("Test1", 
        "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5", "Test6", "Test7", "Test8", 
        "Test9", "Test10", "Test11", "Test12", "Test13", "Test14", "Test15", 
        "Test16"), Year = c(2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
        2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016)), .Names = c("Value", 
        "Label", "Year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 16L
        )), NULL)), .Names = c("ID", "Country", "Subdocuments"), row.names = c(NA, 
        -3L), class = "data.frame")

  class(data$Subdocuments) # "list"

  is.null(data$Subdocuments[[1]]) # FALSE
  is.null(data$Subdocuments[[2]]) # FALSE
  is.null(data$Subdocuments[[3]]) # TRUE
```

The output would be the first two rows of the data.frame

A solution using the package `data.table` would  be ideal. Because i have another extremely large dataset where i want do use this principal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

data.table solution:

```
dt <- as.data.table(data);
dt[!sapply(Subdocuments,is.null)];
##    ID     Country Subdocuments
## 1:  1 Netherlands <data.frame>
## 2:  2     Germany <data.frame>
```

---

Base R solution:

```
data[!sapply(data$Subdocuments,is.null),];
##   ID     Country                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          Subdocuments
## 1  1 Netherlands 5, 5, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 2, Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4, Test5, Test6, Test7, Test8, Test9, Test10, Test11, Test12, Test13, Test14, Test15, Test16, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016
## 2  2     Germany 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 1, 1, 3, Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4, Test5, Test6, Test7, Test8, Test9, Test10, Test11, Test12, Test13, Test14, Test15, Test16, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016
```

Comment: A less reliable but maybe faster way: `data[ lengths(data$Sub) != 0L, ]`